# how to hide volume indicator with swiftui in ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit

I am writing a music player app using apple Media Player and have a button to change the volume and hide the system default volume overlay.
However, all methods I find are based on UIKit.
Like

```
let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: .zero)       
volumeView.clipsToBounds = true
volumeView.alpha = 0.00001
volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = false
view.addSubview(volumeView)
```

And I tried

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import MediaPlayer
struct VolumeView:UIViewRepresentable{
    let volumeView:MPVolumeView
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MPVolumeView {
        volumeView.clipsToBounds = true
        volumeView.alpha = 0.00001
        volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = false
        return volumeView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MPVolumeView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    typealias UIViewType = MPVolumeView
    
    
}
```

It receives the MPVolumeView I created in my view model and I place it in a swiftui view. The indicator disappears but it can't change the volume.
Then I tried to make a new instance of MPVolumeView in UIViewRepresentable and it also didn't work.
I am a green hand in swiftui, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same question and your example helped me to figure it out, you were nearly there apparently.

So here is a complete custom Volume Slider in SwiftUI

```
struct VolumeSliderView: View {

    var primaryColor: Color

    @StateObject var volumeViewModel = VolumeViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
        
            VolumeView()
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
        
            Slider(value: $volumeViewModel.volume, in: 0...1) {
                Text("")
            } minimumValueLabel: {
                Image(systemName: "speaker.fill")
                    .font(.callout)
                    .foregroundColor(primaryColor.opacity(0.6))
            } maximumValueLabel: {
                Image(systemName: "speaker.wave.3.fill")
                    .font(.callout)
                    .foregroundColor(primaryColor.opacity(0.6))
            } onEditingChanged: { isEditing in
                volumeViewModel.setVolume()
            }
            .tint(primaryColor.opacity(0.6))
        }
    }
}

import Foundation
import MediaPlayer

struct VolumeView: UIViewRepresentable{
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MPVolumeView {
    
       let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect.zero)
       volumeView.alpha = 0.001

       return volumeView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MPVolumeView, context: Context) {
    
    }

}
```

It seems that an instance of MPVolumeView needs to be present on the screen at any time, even if it's not visible. Seems a bit hacky but works. If I only hide the view in the `setVolume()` function and even call `volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = false` there, it won't make a difference.

```
class VolumeViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var volume: Float = 0.5

    init() {
        setInitialVolume()
    }

    private func setInitialVolume() {
        volume = AVAudioSession().outputVolume
    }

    func setVolume() {
    
        let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
    
        let slider = volumeView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider
    
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.03)     {
            slider?.setValue(self.volume, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps somebody, as I just found non working examples here on SO.